# Union of Array is not working properly in array of objects JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

Hi I am trying to get the union of array by comparing two array of objects, but the output is not as expected. I need to compare every element in a and b and I need to union the values from const a, but my current implementation is giving me the union of const b. Could anyone help me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Current Implementation:

```
  const a = [
    {id: "123", desc:"ItemOne", prdID:"PR-01"},
    {id: "124", desc:"ItemTwo", prdID:"PR-02"}
    ]
    
    const b = [
    {id: "123", desc:"ItemOne", prdID:"PR-01", tbc:"yes"},
    {id: "124", desc:"ItemTwo", prdID:"PR-02", tbc:"yes"},
    {id: "124", desc:"ItemTwo", prdID:"PR-02", tbc:"no"}
    ]
    
    const Union = [...new Map([...a, ...b].map(ele => [ele.id, ele])).values()];
```

Above implementation is giving the result from b not from a. But I need result from A.

if I changed the position of  and b inside union I am getting the expected output, but I should always give a first not b.

```
const Union = [...new Map([...b, ...a].map(ele => [ele.id, ele])).values()];
```

Above code is working as expected. But I shouldn't interchange the position

Comment: *'Above code is working as expected. But I shouldn't interchange the position'* what do you mean by this? The Map simply overwrites each entry with later entries with the same key, so you need to have the preferred source last in your array. The only alternative using this method would be to reverse the resulting entries array `[...a, ...b].map(ele => [ele.id, ele]).reverse()` but it's far clearer to do it up front.

Comment: can you post your expected output ?

Comment: do you have two accounts?

Comment: @NinaScholz nope

Comment: because of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74887590/compare-two-different-array-of-objects-and-filter-out-the-item

Answer (score 0):

You need to take reduce to fill the map and check if the key exist and keep the value, if so.

```js
const
    a = [{ id: "123", desc:"ItemOne", prdID:"PR-01" }, { id: "124", desc:"ItemTwo", prdID:"PR-02" }],
    b = [{ id: "123", desc:"ItemOne", prdID:"PR-01", tbc:"yes" }, { id: "124", desc:"ItemTwo", prdID:"PR-02", tbc:"yes" }, { id: "124", desc:"ItemTwo", prdID:"PR-02", tbc:"no" }],
    union = Array.from([...a, ...b]
        .reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.id, m.get(o.id) ?? o), new Map)
        .values()
    );
    
console.log(union);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: is there any other way to achieve this without using set and get ?